# Activity with two layout views, where one view has vertical scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to do an activity with two "parts". The first one, uses the top half of the screen, and there, I will show some fields (name, date,...). The second one, uses the bottom half of the same screen, and there, I will show a table, with three columns, and with some rows. The quantity of rows is undefined, because they come from a web service.

My doubt is how to do this second part, with a vertical scrollbar table, where the user will see the first half static, and could be able to roler the bottom half to see all rows of the table (like an iframe). I need to use table, because my cells need to be aligned.

I have already tried tablelayout, listview, gridview, and I can't find a way to show the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Try `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack` for the lower part.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Note though that ScrollView supports one direct child so you may wrap everything up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
MainLayout
    TopHalfElements

    ScrollView
        Linear/relative/frame/whatever layout
            Rows From Webservice etc.
```

You need to have a main layout inside the [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) as it only supports one direct child.